# Join data from more tables to single ADF table

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I am creating ADF application in JDeveloper 12c with Oracle 11g XE database.
I need join more tables to one ADF table. It is possible? I created this model in Toad Data Modeler:
[image]

Model is in Czech language, but it doesn't matter. This is a simple film database. Important is the concept of the model.
I want to have an ADF table that will contain data from multiple tables.

[image]

Unfortunately I did not come to that.
I beg you for advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say whether you are using ADF BC to not. Assuming you are, I would start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/b31974/bcquerying.htm).

Specifically;
Create new VO based on EO as the Base, up-dateable EO. In the next page of the Wizard, select the other tables as the reference EOs.
You will want to have created Associations that represent FKs to make this work.

[This](http://technology.amis.nl/2007/05/09/jdeveloper-11g-model-based-viewobject-list-of-values-and-their-end-to-end-benefit-in-the-web-tier/) may help too.

Or, create a view in MySql and base the View Object on that.

Comment: Your second post is useful for me. Thank you!