# how to get value from another ViewObject with SQL Expression in ADF?

Tags: sql, oracle-adf

i have Employee table , and Department Table

and i've created EOs , VOs and association for them

but when i try to add transient attribute in EmployeesVO to get the department Name it doens'nt show any value

and this is my SQL EXpression

```
(select departmentId from DepartmentView where DepartmentView.departmentId = EmployeesView.departmentId  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is create a JOIN between the Employee VO and the Department EO and add the Department name as a read only attribute. These links may help: [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1774717), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121365/join-data-from-more-tables-to-single-adf-table), and [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/adf/develop/adf-bc-vo-queries.htm).